# NHibernate Interceptor - OnFlushDirty

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, interceptor

What I want to do is to intercept entity on save and truncate some string properties.

The issues is that `OnSave()` triggers only for new `Entity`, but not on changing/updating `Entity`.

Then there is `OnFlushDirty()` interceptor. But I am really confused with this one.

So I want to modify some property of entity on updating entity, like:

```
public bool OnFlushDirty( 
             object entity, 
             object id, 
             object[] currentState, 
             object[] previousState,  
             string[] propertyNames, 
             IType[] types)
{
      bool entityChanged = false;
      for (int i = 0; i < propertyNames.Length; i++)
      {
            var stringType = types[i] as NHibernate.Type.StringType;

            if (stringType != null)
            {
                 if(NeedTruncate(currentState[i]))
                 {
                      currentState[i] = Truncate(currentState[i]);
                      entityChanged = true;
                 }
            }
      }

      return entityChanged;
}
```

So the issue is next. On some blogs like [this one](https://www.targetprocess.com/blog/2006/08/entity-life-cycle-in-nhibernate/) I read that `OnFlushDirty()` is called when entity was changed and saved into database, so the changes to any property here will not be saved into database.

But in [githab.io](http://mausch.github.io/nhibernate-3.2.0GA/html/c3c18926-d5a8-3b22-d113-d495bd20b52e.htm#seeAlsoToggle) documentation it says:

> The interceptor may modify the detected currentState, which will be
>   propagated to both the database and the persistent object. Note that
>   all flushes end in an actual synchronization with the database, in
>   which as the new currentState will be propagated to the object, but
>   not necessarily (immediately) to the database. It is strongly
>   recommended that the interceptor not modify the previousState.

It also says:

> Called when an object is detected to be dirty, during a flush.

So I am not sure what exactly means

> Called when an object is detected to be dirty

Also regarding to this documentation, the changes will be saved into database, just not necessary immediately.

Anyway, by testing this in my project, this works and when `OnFlushDirty()` is called and it changes value of some property it's also saved in database and all seams to be working fine.

So my question is: Is this correct to do? As I said, I tested it with my project and on changing/updating entity `OnFlushDirty()` is called, property is changed and saved into database as well. 
Just because all of this, and weak documentation, I am not sure if I can run into some issues with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do, in a similar case, is override the `FindDirty` method of the interceptor, and return an array of indexes for the properties that have changes (or that you will change in the flushdirty).

In your case, you could override that method and check in that method whether or not you have some string properties that should be truncated.  If so, return the indexes of those properties.

By doing so, you should be sure that `OnFlushDirty` is always called when it is necessary for you.

Next to that, `OnFlushDirty` should also return true if you have modified a persistent property in that method, which you do not do as far as I can see in your code that is posted here.

Comment: Yes, I am returning true if I have modified a persistent property, just I made mistake with code in question, please check the code updated now.
So as soon as I override `FindDirty` to return `true` if I have to modify some property and also return `true` from `OnFlushDirty` if I have modified some property, I can be sure that `OnFlushDirty` will allways be called when I need it and that it will update the property in the object (Entity) and in Database as well?

Comment: Just `FindDirty` returns  and array of int `int[]`, how I can override it and return `true`

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit.   I'm not sure whether or not you can modify the property itself in the FindDirty method ....

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't need to modify it in the `FindDirty`, and  as I understand you I don't need to modify it there. Just want to find if some property has to be modified and return and array of int[] to be sure that  `OnFlushDirty` will be called where will I modify the property.

I am going to test this and accept answers, but please if you can explain to me what means here "FindingDirty". What Nhibernate default mechanism do here? What makes an `Entity` dirty by default?

Comment: An entity is dirty when some property is modified; in other words, when an entity is retrieved from the DB and modified, it is dirty until changes are saved.
FindingDirty means: find if there are any properties that are changed so that flushing (writing to DB) will occur

Comment: Great, I supposed that's it, but I couldn't find any detailed definition in documentation. That is exactly what I have to know, The I don't have to override `FindDirty` as I have to change entity only if some property is changed. It's just good enough to know that changes to entity will change the record in DB